# Can i change the 'what's new' section for my app on the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I can't figure out how to edit that part, and unfortunately i used `&trade;` in it, which works perfectly well on all previews and on iTunes, but when you open it on an iPhone, it literally reads `&trade;`, and now I don't think I'm able to edit it. Could I contact Apple to get them to correct this for me?

Comment: It's certainly worth a try contacting them.  Don't forget to grovel  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change this aspect of an app once it is approved on your own.

To do that, contact Apple Developer Support by E-Mail

-> devprograms@apple.com

That said, simply pushing another version update might be faster as Developer Support takes quite some time to respond.